# How can I get only the array element as output instead of whole object in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, objectid

Below is my code to display review array data which is part of the restaurant collection object:

```
async get(reviewId) {
    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    reviewId = ObjectId(reviewId)
  
    const r = await restaurantsCollection.findOne(
      { reviews: { $elemMatch: { _id : reviewId } } },
      {"projection" : { "reviews.$": true }}
    )
  
    return r
  }
```

My object looks like:

```
{
  _id: '6176e58679a981181d94dfaf',
  name: 'The Blue Hotel',
  location: 'Noon city, New York',
  phoneNumber: '122-536-7890',
  website: 'http://www.bluehotel.com',
  priceRange: '$$$',
  cuisines: [ 'Mexican', 'Italian' ],
  overallRating: 0,
  serviceOptions: { dineIn: true, takeOut: true, delivery: true },
  reviews: []
}
```

My output looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "6174cfb953edbe9dc5054f99", // restaurant Id
    "reviews": [
        {
            "_id": "6176df77d4639898b0c155f0", // review Id
            "title": "This place was great!",
            "reviewer": "scaredycat",
            "rating": 5,
            "dateOfReview": "10/13/2021",
            "review": "This place was great! the staff is top notch and the food was delicious!  They really know how to treat their customers"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want as output:

```
{
    "_id": "6176df77d4639898b0c155f0",
    "title": "This place was great!",
    "reviewer": "scaredycat",
    "rating": 5,
    "dateOfReview": "10/13/2021",
    "review": "This place was great! the staff is top notch and the food was delicious!  They really know how to treat their customers"
}
```

How can I get the output as only the review without getting the restaurant ID or the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the query operators, `find` and `findOne` do not allow "advanced" restructure of data.

So you have 2 alternatives:

1. The more common approach will be to do this in code, usually people either use some thing [mongoose post trigger](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) or have some kind of "shared" function that handles all of these transformations, this is how you avoid code duplication.
2. Use the aggregation framework, like so:

```
const r = await restaurantsCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { reviews: { $elemMatch: { _id : reviewId } } },
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                    {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$reviews",
                            as: "review",
                            cond: {$eq: ["$$review._id", reviewId]}
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
return r[0]
```